# Mysql Inner Joın At least one match is required

Tags: mysql

I created two tables. I keep the topics in one and the comments in this topic in the other.

When I want to view the topics, I want to see the total number of comments on the topic from the comments table.

But if there is not at least one comment in the query I wrote, it does not bring results. How can I see my topics even if there is no comment on my Inner Join query?

Thank you.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT portal_topics.id, portal_topics.topicDetail, portal_topics.topicName,portal_topics.topicCategory,portal_topics.topicAuthor, portal_topics.topicTıme, portal_topics.topicAvatar,portal_topics.topicViews, portal_topics.topicLikes, COUNT(portal_comments.id) as totalCommentCount FROM `portal_topics` 

INNER JOIN portal_comments ON portal_comments.topic_id = portal_topics.id  
WHERE portal_comments.topic_id = portal_topics.id  
GROUP BY portal_topics.topicName
```

Note: The query does not contain any Syntax errors. I have arranged the column names in English for everyone to understand. I may have made a mistake in this section.

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Nick I did what you said. I still cannot view the topics that are not registered in the comments table.

Comment: You also need to remove the `WHERE` clause; it is already covered by the `ON` clause.

Comment: I got it. Thank u for help. @Nick